# Alternative method to ajax json

Tags: ajax, json

I develop a web solution for a company and I want to get php variables to my pages using ajax. The problem is that the server of that company is somewhat old and I cannot use json using `jason_encode` for that. Is there any alternative method to do that without using json? Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: That would depend on what types of encoding there are available. You could try XML for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
formData = {
    // all your parameters here
    param1: param1,
    param2: param2
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "https://www.example.com/test",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        //success handling
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handling
    }
});
```